# Filter across tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to add a calculated column where I have a filter on. This is in the sales targets table. How can I add a filter which filters on city with the ordval from the sales table?
[image]

Comment: What do you want your calculated column to be?

Comment: I want my calculated column to sum the data from the corresponding city.

Comment: So you want another column on the `Sales` table that sums up the `ordval` for every row in `Sales` where `cno` matches to the same `City`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: I was wondering where you wanted to see the calculated value, in which visual. I also wondered if you have a bidrectional filtering issue? I had another thought that you should put city on your sales table to make everything work more simply. Sorry about the brain dump :-)

Comment: Hi, I want to add the calculated value in the Sales Targets table. As far as I know there are no filtering issues. Filtering on the city is the following code: `Sales 2016 = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[ordval]))`, now I want to add a filter which sums the month. So if the month in Sales Targets is January, it should only sum sales from January

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something  like this:

```
SumOrdval =
VAR RelatedCity = LOOKUPVALUE(Customer[Citycode], Customer[Cno], Sales[cno])
VAR RelatedCnos = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Customer[cno]), Customer[Citycode] = RelatedCity)
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[ordval]),
    ALL(Sales),
    Sales[cno] IN RelatedCnos
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Sales[cno] is not recognized. Saying "A single value for column 'cno' in table 'Sales' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result."

Comment: Did you try to create it as a measure instead of a calculated column on the `Sales` table?

Comment: Yes, it is the exact same problem. It happens on the first Sales[cno]

Comment: You asked for a calculated column, so that's what I wrote. It doesn't work the same way as a measure. If you need it to work as a measure also, then replace the first `Sales[cno]` with `CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE(Customer[cno]))`.